# Is it possible to access controller parameters when overriding ClaimsAuthorizationManager?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, claims-based-identity

I have created my own AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager to help with authorization.  I am using the out of the box attribute ClaimsPrinciplePermission.

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Operation="Show", Resource="Account")]
public ActionResult Index(int? id)
```

The problem/question, from within my public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context) method i would like to get to the controller parameter id.  Is this possible?

I need to do logic based on the parameter id within CheckAccess. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access this parameter directly from

```
context.HttpContext.Request.Params["id"]
```

or

```
context.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("id")
```

Comment: Unfortunately within the CheckAccess method context of type AuthorizationContext and HttpContext is not a property of .

i.e. AuthorizationContext does not contain a definition for HttpContext

Comment: What is the main goal of creating such Manager?

Comment: I am using the out of the box ClaimsPrinciplePermission attribute with actions/resource identified however access to that particular method by a user is specific to the id passed into the method.  i.e. a user can have access based on the id passed in.  As such, i need to grab the controller method parameter id within the custom AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager.  I can get action, resource but not the parameter used.

Comment: If this is just filtering of users based on roles or account permissions you should just override existing solution: Authentication filter.

Comment: This is more authorization not authentication.  In addition, i am using ClaimsPrincipalPermission attribute to specify the resource/action.  With this attribute in order to add custom authorization you create your own authorization manager and derive from out of the box AuthorizationManager